# Can I get a notification emailed to me every time a contact with a certain tag is updated?

Tags: civireport, activities

Our team would like to be notified any time a certain group of contacts are updated. Ideally this notification would contain the most current version of the contact profile, as well as the previous version of the profile so that our team can compare the old information with the updated fields. Is such an automated notification possible? Is there a way we could do this with a scheduled report?

Comment: Can you clarify how this 'certain gropu of contacts' are being updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think meeting all these requirements would involve custom code. Some possible approaches to meet some of the requirements...

(1) In Advanced Search, search for contacts with the relevant tag and under Change Log, modified date yesterday. Save as a smart group. Then set up a Constituent Detail report filtered by this smart group. Have it emailed daily.
This will not give you the contacts' previous data.

(2) Enable logging, at Administer -> System Settings -> Misc. Use the Contact Logging Report.
This does not allow filtering by tag. However this feature could be added, with code customisation.

(3) A custom solution using the [civicrm_pre hook](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_pre) to provide real-time notification of changes. This could include before-and-after values.

(4) A custom solution running under cron, using Civi logging to check for changes and retrieve previous values.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use mix of civirules & civi email API extension from here https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules
and  https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi

may need some extra programming work on them, i guess.